# What are different ways to share high frequency data between Python applications?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, redis

I wrote an application that reads in serial data, does some stuff, and then writes it to a csv file. I run a separate instance of the application for each serial line using supervisor. Some of the data from different serial streams needs to be combined and or transformed to create new, custom data types that then gets written to a csv file or broadcast over UDP.

I don't really care about old data, only the most recently received. In fact, it would be nice if the data timed out after a while so that old data wasn't used if new data stopped coming in.

There are about 40 or more data streams coming in, some at 1Hz and others at 30Hz or more.

The host computer is a Linux system.

**What some of the ways to share data between processes?**

**Would something like Redis work for this? What about a sqlite database? What are some of the trade offs?**

Comment: You mentioned the frequency. What about the bandwidth? What is the size of the data?

Comment: @marco.m They are mostly NMEA standard messages, so anywhere from 50 to 150 bits per message, but a few are much longer. I think the highest bandwidth one is ~700 bits per message at 5Hz, so about 3,500 bit/sec.

Comment: Where are the other processes you want to share data with? On the same host or on the network? (Since you mention sqlite, I think on the same host). "Share" is generic. Is that consumer/producer (once a consumer reads the data, that data must disappear) or the same data must stay available for multiple sinks?

Comment: @marco.m As you said, the same host. The data should remain available for multiple reads. The data for a stream should also only remain available until new data arrives for that stream. As an example, we have a stream of data with relative wind speed and another stream with speed over ground, we want to take data from both to make a stream of true wind speed in real-time. We also have a stream of relative water speed and need to use the same speed over ground to get true water speed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a possible design is a simple pub/sub system, such as [NATS](https://nats.io/). You don't need persistence, so plain NATS
is good. Another possibility is MQTT.

- Each process reading a serial line would be a producer on a given "NATS subject" (possibly removing the need to write to CSV files).
- Each process that combines multiple serial line streams would be a consumer of multiple "NATS subjects".

Consider that the consumer(s) would need logic to cope with the different rate of the different streams, no matter the technology used.

SQLite, although a very good product, doesn't seem the natural fit for this application,
since it supports multiple readers but only a single writer at a time (see [WAL](https://sqlite.org/wal.html)).

You could still consider SQLite as the data format instead of CSV. It is not
clear if these CSV files are meant to be long-lived or not. It is also possible
to import/export CSV files to/from SQLite.

I cannot comment on Redis because Redis is many things and you don't specify
what you are referring to (the K/V store? the queue?).